# Trying to access data from get request i get Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've found a few other questions for the same problem but none helped.

here are my `list.page.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['list.page.scss']
})
export class ListPage implements OnInit {


  private selectedItem: any;
  private icons = [
    'flask',
    'wifi',
    'beer',
    'football',
    'basketball',
    'paper-plane',
    'american-football',
    'boat',
    'bluetooth',
    'build'
  ];
  public items: Array<{ title: string; note: string; icon: string }> = [];
  fostan: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient){
  const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
})
}
this.fostan = this.httpClient.get('https://www.fostania.com/api/items/',httpOptions);
this.fostan.subscribe(data => {
  this.fostan = data;
console.log('my data: ', data);
})
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  // add back when alpha.4 is out
  // navigate(item) {
  //   this.router.navigate(['/list', JSON.stringify(item)]);
  // }
}
```

and here is how I tried to call it from the `.html` file

```
  <ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let fos of fostan">
  title  {{ fos.title }}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

But I get this error in my console :

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

So any idea on how to convert this result into an array to be able to access it from the HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fostan** is of type **Observable**, it is not an array :

Change the line :

```
this.fostan = data;
```

By :

```
this.items = data;
```

And

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let fos of fostan">
```

By :

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let fos of items">
```

Answer (score 1):

When the component mounts `this.fostan` is an observable, and so `let fos of fostan` happens on the observable.

You should move the subscription data to a new instance variable

eg.

```
  this.items = data;

  ...

  *ngFor="let fos or items"
```